# PHP group multidimensional array by repeated values

Tags: php

I have a simple two dimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John
            [company] => One
            [price] => 12.22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John
            [company] => Two
            [price] => 14.33
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Mike
            [company] => One
            [price] => 15.11
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Mike
            [company] => Two
            [price] => 10.12
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Paul
            [company] => One
            [price] => 42.22
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Paul
            [company] => Two
            [price] => 56.62
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Paul
            [company] => Three
            [price] => 16.12
        )
)
```

I need to group `id` and `name`, then create an array with different values something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John
            [companies] => array (
                                  array(
                                        [company] => One 
                                        [price] => 12.22
                                  )
                                  array(
                                        [company] => Two
                                        [price] => 14.33
                                  )
                           )               
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Mike
            [companies] => array (
                                  array(
                                        [company] => One 
                                        [price] => 15.11
                                  )
                                  array(
                                        [company] => Two
                                        [price] => 10.12
                                  )
                           )               
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Paul
            [companies] => array (
                                  array(
                                        [company] => One 
                                        [price] => 42.22
                                  )
                                  array(
                                        [company] => Two
                                        [price] => 56.62
                                  )
                                  array(
                                        [company] => Three
                                        [price] => 16.12
                                  )
                           )              
        )        
)
```

What is the best way to do it with PHP?

This is my attemp:

```
<?php
$items=array();
$temp = 0;
$companies = array('uno','dos','tres');
foreach ($values as $value) {

  if ($temp == $value['id'] )
    continue;                            
  else
    $temp == $value['id'];

  foreach ($companies as $key => $company){
    foreach ($values as $item){
      if ($item['id'] == $temp && $item['company'] == $key)
        $value['company'][$key] = $item['price'];
    }
  }

  $items[] = $value;

}
```

Comment: I can think of a few ways to do it. What have you tried so far? This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: added my attemp

Comment: You say you want to group by name, but I don't see `name` mentioned in your code.

Comment: I want to group by repeated values: 'id' and 'name', the rest insert in an array

Comment: Did this data come from a database? If so, can you modify the query? If it is a SQL database you could use *GROUP BY*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `id` as the key for the new array, then just append a new array with the next `company` and `price`

```
foreach($array as $v) {
    $result[$v['id']]['id']          = $v['id'];
    $result[$v['id']]['name']        = $v['name'];
    $result[$v['id']]['companies'][] = array('company' => $v['company'],
                                             'price'   => $v['price']);
}
```

If you need to re-index it (probably not):

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks!