# php convert multi dimension resultant array on basis of month array

Tags: php, arrays

Below is my resultant array and month array

```
$resultVal = Array
     (  
        [0] => Array
             (
                 [0] => Array
                    (
                            [crate] => 13.51
                            [ucount] => 36
                            [udate] => 2016-06-30
                    )
             )
        )

 $MonthArray =array("June 2016","July 2016");
```

I m using array_combine and loop through resultant array and using in_array function to loop through each month with resultant array
Below is my trying code,

```
            $final_array = array_combine ( $MonthArray, array_fill ( 0, count ( $MonthArray ), 0 ) );
            foreach ( $new_array as $item ) {
                        $month = $item ['udate'];
                        if (in_array ( $month, $MonthArray )) {
                            $final_array [$month] += $item ['crate'];
                        }
                    }
                    $i = 0;
                    $finalArray = array ();
                    foreach ( $final_array as $key => $value ) {
                        $finalArray [$i] ['crate'] = "$value";
                        $finalArray [$i] ['udate'] = date ( "M jS Y", strtotime ( $key ) );
                        $i ++;
                    }
```

I am getting udate and create but I also want ucount. 
Below is Expected result is,

```
    Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [crate] => 13.51
                        [ucount] => 36
                        [udate] => June 2016
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [crate] => 0
                        [ucount] => 0
                        [udate] => July 2016
                    )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this?

```
   <?php
   $resultVal = array(0 => array
                (0 => array
                       (
                               'crate' => '13.51',
                               'ucount' => '36',
                               'udate' => '2017-06-30',
                       ))
                ,
                    array(  1 => array
                       (
                               'crate' => '70',
                               'ucount' => '25',
                               'udate' => '2017-06-30',
                       )
                )
           );

   $MonthArray =array("June 2016","July 2016");

   $keys = array_keys($MonthArray);
   $length = count($keys);
   $c = array();
   foreach($resultVal as $sub) {
       if(!is_array($sub)) {
           $sub = array();
       }
       $c[] = array_combine(array_pad($keys, count($sub), NULL), array_pad(array_values($sub), $length, NULL)); // Pad removes the possibility of a warning
   }

   $i = 0;
   $finalArray = array ();
   foreach ( $c as $key => $value ) {  
        $finalArray [$i] ['crate'] = $value[0]['crate'];
       $finalArray [$i] ['ucount'] = $value[0]['ucount'];
       $finalArray [$i] ['udate'] = date ( "M jS Y", strtotime ( $value[0]['udate'] ) );
       $i ++;
   }

   print_r( $finalArray);

   ?>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ify0-uhxv

Comment: Hi Vel u r answer is very close.But in resultant array having only one index and in month array having two month.So I want  July 2016 crate and count become zero.

Comment: Thanks.this is when both resultant array and month array index are same but in month array one more value is there "Augest 2017" and for this month we have to set both crate and ucount zero.

Comment: I didnt get you.. can you post your array?

Comment: $resultArray = Array( [0] => Array([0] => Array(
                            [crate] => 13.51
                            [ucount] => 36
                            [udate] => 2016-06-3)))

Below is month array
$MonthArray =array("June 2016","July 2016");
Expected array:
Array([0] => Array([crate] => 13.51
                     [ucount] => 36
                     [udate] => June 2016
                    )[1] => Array
                    ([crate] => 0
                      [ucount] => 0
                      [udate] => July 2016
                    )
            )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619145/php-group-multidimensional-array-by-repeated-values good example

Answer (score 0):

My previous coding attempt assumed (falsely, I believe) that the `udate`s were always the last day of the month.

This updated answer will elegantly process your array data regardless of the day in the date value.  `isset()` is the fastest way to check the lookup array. Generating new keys for each subarray in `$lookup` ensures that this method will perform optimally.  The `udate` values are also modified before being stored in `$lookup` so that there is no extra handling in the second loop, just conditional storing.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0bf5597c0dbf4321704d4a183a9bd61c29d97400))

```
$resultVal=[
    [
        ['crate'=>9.99,'ucount'=>30,'udate'=>'2016-05-31'], // "May" will not be in the desired range (just for demonstration)
        ['crate'=>13.51,'ucount'=>36,'udate'=>'2016-06-30']
    ]
];
// prepare existing data:
foreach($resultVal[0] as $a){
    $newdate=date('F Y',strtotime($a['udate']));  // generate date in desired format
    $a['udate']=$newdate;  // update udate value before storing in lookup array
    $lookup[$newdate]=$a;  // assign associative key using udate for faster lookup
}

// blend existing data with default data as result array:
$MonthArray=['June 2016','July 2016','August 2016'];  // month-year range
foreach($MonthArray as $monthyear){
    $result[]=(isset($lookup[$monthyear])?$lookup[$monthyear]:['crate'=>0,'ucount'=>0,'udate'=>$monthyear]);
    //         ^^^^^-- if found ----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                                      else use defaults ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'crate' => 13.51,
    'ucount' => 36,
    'udate' => 'June 2016',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'crate' => 0,
    'ucount' => 0,
    'udate' => 'July 2016',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'crate' => 0,
    'ucount' => 0,
    'udate' => 'August 2016',
  ),
)
```